# Circular UIView with a gradually fading out border

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I have managed to make a circle with a radial gradient colour like so:

[image: Circle with yellow outer gradient]

```
@interface CircleView : UIView
@end

@implementation CircleView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    const CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    NSArray *gradientColors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           (id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor,
                           (id)[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor, nil];
    CGFloat gradientLocations[] = {0.0, 0.5};
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (CFArrayRef)gradientColors, gradientLocations);

    UIBezierPath *roundedRectanglePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [roundedRectanglePath fill];
    [roundedRectanglePath addClip];
    CGPoint gradCenter= CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
    CGContextDrawRadialGradient (context, gradient, gradCenter, 0, gradCenter, rect.size.width, kCGGradientDrawsBeforeStartLocation);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
}
@end
```

Making sure, when adding the `UIView` to the storyboard and setting its class to `CircleView`, it's width = height.

However I want to make the `[UIColor yellowColor]` into `[UIColor clearColor]` so it looks like the red fades out, i.e. the outside is transparent.

I find that by changing the `[UIColor yellowColor]` to `[UIColor clearColor]`, the outside becomes black like:

[image: Circle with clear outer gradient]

How do I make the red colour gradually fade out in a circular way - because setting `[UIColor yellowColor]` to `[UIColor clearColor]` clearly doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

In HTML terms, `+[UIColor clearColor]` is effectively #000000 with an alpha of 0.0. In other words, the `UIColor` that is named `clear` is transparent black.

This is fine in most circumstances where you use this color, because it's completely transparent. However, when you're creating a gradient between two colors it can have the drastic effect you see here.

You probably want to use the `-[UIColor withAlphaComponent:]` method, e.g.

```
UIColor *transparentRed = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.0];
```